# Javascript function working fine in IE but not in chrome and Firefox except when $(document).ready() is launch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome

For my project I need to get some data from a distant server to be display in a table who is refresh every X times with AJAX.

Actually it's working fine on IE, but when I try on Chrome and Firefox the AJAX function doesn't work out of the $(document).ready() event...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  doLaunch(); // This works
});

setInterval(function () {
  if ($_dragStart == null) {
    doClear(); // working but no AJAX in there

    doRecup(); // not working
   }
}, 10000);


function doLaunch() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'journalier.aspx/copyDataYesterday',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    complete : function () {
      doRecup(); // working in there
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + status + ")");
      alert(err); 
    }
  });
};

function doRecup() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'journalier.aspx/getDataNav',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: '{datePlanning:"' + '<%= Session["Planning_Date"].ToString() %>' + '"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
       var dateMaj = document.getElementById("MainContent_dateTimePlanning").value; 

       for (i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++) { 
         if (data.d[(i * 5) + 3] == dateMaj) { 
           var objet = document.getElementById(data.d[(i * 5) + 2]); 

           var row = document.getElementById("MainContent_" + data.d[i * 5]); 

           if (row != null) {

             if (data.d[(i * 5) + 1] == "Ressource")
                $(objet).appendTo(row.cells[12].childNodes[0]);
             else if (data.d[(i * 5) + 1] == "Conducteur")
                $(objet).appendTo(row.cells[4].childNodes[0]);
             else if (data.d[(i * 5) + 1] == "Chauffeur")
                $(objet).appendTo(row.cells[6].childNodes[0]);
             else if (data.d[(i * 5) + 1] == "Engin")
                $(objet).appendTo(row.cells[5].childNodes[0]);
             else if (data.d[(i * 5) + 1] == "Chef")
                $(objet).appendTo(row.cells[11].childNodes[0]);
             else if (data.d[(i * 5) + 1] == "Consigne" && data.d[(i * 5) + 4] != null) {
                row.cells[9].childNodes[0].innerText = data.d[(i * 5) + 4];
                row.cells[9].childNodes[1].value = data.d[(i * 5) + 4];
             }
             else if (data.d[(i * 5) + 1] == "Carburant" && data.d[(i * 5) + 4] != null) {
                row.cells[3].childNodes[0].innerText = data.d[(i * 5) + 4];
                row.cells[3].childNodes[1].value = data.d[(i * 5) + 4];
             }

          } 

        }

      } 

      var currDate = new Date();

      var HH = currDate.getHours();
      var MM = currDate.getMinutes();

      var Time = HH + ":" + MM ;

      document.getElementById("MainContent_lblDateLastMaj").innerText = "Dernière Mise à Jour : " + Time;

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + status + ")");
      alert(err); 
    },
    complete: function () {
      alert("Complete!");
    }
  });
};

function doClear() {
  for (k = 0; k < document.getElementById("MainContent_divTabProjet").childNodes.length / 2; k++) { 
   for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows.length; i++) {

     document.getElementById("MainContent_lblCarbu" + i).innerText = ""; 
     document.getElementById("MainContent_lblCarbu" + i).value = "";

   for (j = 0; j < document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[4].childNodes[0].childNodes.length ; j++) { 

      $(document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[4].childNodes[0].childNodes[j]).appendTo($("#MainContent_divTabRessources"));

   }

   for (j = 0; j < document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[5].childNodes[0].childNodes.length ; j++) {

      $(document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[5].childNodes[0].childNodes[j]).appendTo($("#MainContent_divTabEngins"));

   }

   for (j = 0; j < document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[6].childNodes[0].childNodes.length ; j++) { 

      $(document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[6].childNodes[0].childNodes[j]).appendTo($("#MainContent_divTabRessources"));

   }

   document.getElementById("MainContent_lblConsigne" + i).innerText = ""; 
   document.getElementById("MainContent_lblConsigne" + i).value = "";

   for (j = 0; j < document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[11].childNodes[0].childNodes.length ; j++) {

      $(document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[11].childNodes[0].childNodes[j]).appendTo($("#MainContent_divTabRessources"));

   }

   for (j = 0; j < document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[12].childNodes[0].childNodes.length ; j++) { 

       $(document.getElementById("MainContent_tabProjetJourAgence" + k).rows[i].cells[12].childNodes[0].childNodes[j]).appendTo($("#MainContent_divTabRessources"));

   }
  } 
 } 
};
```

**Update :** When I launch the function manually in the console it works fine. So the problem is that the function is not launch in the interval, but the doClear function is launch every 10 seconds ... If I put the doClear function in commentary the doRecup function is trigger every 10 seconds.

**Update 2** : If I do that it works

```
setInterval(function () {
 if ($_dragStart == null) {
   doClear(); 
 }
}, 10000);
setInterval(function () {
 if ($_dragStart == null) {
   doRecup();
 }
}, 10000);
```

**Update 3 :** So now I do that :

```
setInterval(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    doClear();
  }, 1);
  setTimeout(function () {
    doRecup();
  }, 1);
}, 10000);
```

Well it far from being perfect and it's certainly not recommended but actually it works so ...

Comment: What's not working? Do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: @anderssonola I got no error, but the doRecup function is only launch in the ready event and not every 10 seconds. The doClear function works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you call the function based on whether or not the ajax request is complete. By calling the function in a setInterval, the ajax call will be made every x seconds whether or not the request is complete, which is not a good practice in my opinion. I would do something like this:

```
function doRecup() {
.......
.......
.......
.......
complete: function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    doRecup();
    doClear();
  }, 10000)
}
.......
.......
.......
}
```

And comment/remove the function from:

```
setInterval(function () {
  if ($_dragStart == null) {
    //doClear(); // working but no AJAX in there

    //doRecup(); // not working

   }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: With that method can I be sure that the doRecup() would be trigger after the doClear()?

Comment: See the edits. Did you try to see if it worked? And it'd be good to rewirte your doClear() function with jQuery as you anyway use jquery, which would be more readable and easier.

Comment: It didn't work, the issue is still the same, the doClear() is trigger but not the doRecup(), because the doRecup() must be place after the doClear() since the table need to be empty when the success event is trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting `var $_dragStart = null` anywhere..? Because, for me your code working.

Anyway, you can use `custom ajax error method` to know what is happening there.. because your code `'var err = eval("(" + status + ")");'` not working and its giving error.

I am sharing with you my function

**`Custom Ajax Error Handling Code:`**

```
/**
 * Custom Ajax Error Method
 * 
 * @param jqXHR
 * @param exception
 * @returns {string}
 */
function ajaxError(jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert('Not connected.\nPlease verify your network connection.');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
        alert('The requested page not found. [404]');
    } else if (jqXHR.status === 500) {
        alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        alert('Time out error.');
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        alert('Ajax request aborted.');
    } else {
        alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
}
```

and you can use like this:

**`Example Code:`**

```
function doLaunch() {
    // ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'ajaxCall.php',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        complete : function () {
            console.log('Calling: Ajax Complete doLaunch()');
            doRecup(); // working in there
        },
        error : ajaxError
    });
    // end ajax call
};
```

your code working in fiddle. just check it..

Fiddle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/9QRbu/)

Comment: I think my problem does not come from the AJAX, it's more like it comme from my doClear() function ...